# Iterate over files in directory using bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to iterate over the files in given directory. I tried using the for loop for the same... but I have one another loop inside this loop where I need to read multiple files till the condition is true within that loop to upload at a time... but withing inner loop I am able to access only one file since file iterator loop is outside the inner loop.
Is there any thing like file.getNext so that i can access number of files inside the loop without using index/loop.

I need something like this:

```
while [ count -le $uploadRate ]
do
   files="$files,directory.getNextFile"
   $(curl -o $log_Path -T "{$files}" url)
done
```

where `$files` will have number of files uploaded at a time
I don't want to load the files into array since directory has huge number of files, so array is not feasible option, so would like to iterate over directory like getNext file.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is your inner loop? Also, why do you have `curl` inside `$(...)`, and where is the closing parenthesis?

Comment: the above while loop is inner loop and I want to read 5 files at a time inside that loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your outer loop like this for reading all the files/directories in a directory `/somedir/`:

```
filesToBeRead=5
chunkFiles=()
for f in /somedir/*; do
    chunkFiles+=( "$f" )
    if [[ ${#chunkFiles[@]} -eq 5 ]]; then
        processChunkFiles( "${chunkFiles[@]}" )
        chunkFiles=()
    fi
done
processChunkFiles( "${chunkFiles[@]}" )
```

**PS:** You need to write a `processChunkFiles` function to handle/process 5 files.

Comment: But to read the files i want apply another condition like read 5 files at a time.. so how should I go for that.. I want like this if(filesToBeRead == 5)
 #then read first 5 files
  and do some operations

Comment: Hey, I am facing some issue with this. since we are using "for f in /somedir/*;" which itself works like array as it loads all files in f. So if i keep files in thousands. The processing time is getting slowed..can you please suggest any feasible solution so that the f object will not have to worry abt the number of files present under that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Put the filenames in an array, and iterate through it in groups of 5:

```
files=(/path/to/dir/*)
nfiles=${#files[@]}
for ((i = 0; i < nfiles; i += 5)); do
    for ((j = i; j < i+5; j++)); do
        # Do something with ${files[$j]}
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Actually I don't want to use array since I have millions of files to be read and I don't think reading files into array will be the feasible solution since the array size will be large
Let me knw if you think otherwise. and if we have any other alternative.

Comment: The inner "j" for loop ends up going over all indices multiple times, it should have instead limited the range

`for ((j = i; j < i+5; j++)); do`